# Why was 不 (etymon of 아) pronounced *An in Old Korean?

Tags: hanja, phonology

The IPA for 不 in [2021 Mandarin](https://easypronunciation.com/en/chinese-pinyin-phonetic-transcription-converter) is pʷu<sup>4</sup>, and in [2021 Cantonese](https://toolbox.lotusfa.com/ipa/cantonese/index.html) is [/pɐt](https://open-dict-data.github.io/ipa-lookup/yue/?#)5. These don't sound like *An.

1. From what did *An* phonologically change?
2. Can you please expound the steps of 不's phonological change?

I quote [不知 - Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E7%9F%A5#Old_Korean).

> Etymology
>
> The basic negating root of the Old Korean negatives is disputed. Because all conventional reconstructions begin with *ant-, many South Korean linguists, including Lee Seung-jae, have proposed that the base form was *anto-, producing *[不冬](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E5%86%AC#Old_Korean)* (*ANtol), *[不只](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E5%8F%AA#Old_Korean)* (*ANTOk), and (via deletion of the minimal vowel ) *[不知](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E7%9F%A5#Old_Korean)* (*ANti). Other scholars, including both Koreans and [Alexander Vovin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Vovin), have argued that the negative root is *an and that *tol, *tok, and *ti are as of yet poorly understood suffixes. Vovin notes that likely borrowings in Tungusic appear to suggest that the root was *an-. In the case of *[不知](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E7%9F%A5#Old_Korean)*, the orthographic variation, perhaps reflecting dialectal differences, may also be suggestive of an originally *an- root.
>
> This was probably borrowed at some very ancient period into Proto-Northern Tungusic as *anti, producing forms such as [Udege language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udege_language) *[anči](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=an%C4%8Di&action=edit&redlink=1)* and [Even language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_language) *[āt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C4%81t#Even)*.

Answer (score 2):

There's a misunderstanding here - 「不」 is not the etymon of 「아」. Please carefully notice the [reconstruction notes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%8D%E5%86%AC#Reconstruction_notes); reproduced below with some additions for emphasis:

> The second character (冬) is a common Old Korean **phonogram** for the syllable *tol. The first syllable (不) is a **logogram** conventionally reconstructed as *AN because the sequence 不冬 is used in fourteenth-century Idu to write the Middle Korean negator 아니 (Yale: ani), and the Middle Korean Idu tradition preserves many elements of Old Korean orthography. There is also direct phonogramic evidence that the negating noun 不知 was read as *ANti, and the cross-linguistic unlikelihood of having entirely separate roots for verbal and nominal negation is another, if circumstantial, point of evidence for reconstructing the **logogram** as *AN.

- 「不」 is used as a *logogram*, that is, for its *semantic value* (not **phonetic value**), to represent the Korean root ***AN** (meaning *not*).
- 「冬」 is used as a *phonogram*, that is, for its **phonetic value** (not *semantic value*, which would be *winter*), to represent the Korean syllable ***tol**.

You can see this with the alternative spelling 「非冬」, which still represents the same word (***ANtol**); 「不」 and 「非」 are synonyms, read in Korean using the same Korean root, not its Chinese-derived sound value.

These systems were pre- or alternative-to-Hangul ways of representing Korean using Chinese characters. See the following for more information:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idu_script
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gugyeol

Comment: Thanks. So where did the phoneme *AN hail from? Can you please respond in, by editing, your answer? Comment chains are
cumbersome to read.